# iBeaconを使ったアプリについて

Tags: monaca, ibeacon

iBeacon発信機のNear圏内に入ったら、プッシュ通知を行いたいのですが、（よくあるクーポンを表示する処理など）
http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/sampleapp/samples/ibeacon/などを見ても、Cordovaでバックグラウンドでビーコンを検知し処理を行う方法がわかりません。何か参考になるページなどはありませんでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。